# How to call web service using post method with request paramters for the below api

Tags: objective-c, api, rest, post, get

I have an path:

```
file:////var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5421D684-D466-44F1-AEF5-7390598B5647/Documents/2016-07-29-17-00-12-0.MOV
```

By using this path i want to post my video using the below API:

`139.162.12.178/mediaone/sample/instagram.php?url=<image_path>&image_name=<image_id>`

Please help me out    .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending `POST` requests in iOS is quite easy; and there's no need for an additional framework.

---

### `POST` Request:

We begin by creating our `POST`'s `body` (ergo. what we'd like to send) as an `NSString`, and converting it to `NSData`.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test=Message&this=isNotReal"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
```

Next up, we read the `postData`'s `length`, so we can pass it along in the request.

```
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
```

Now that we have what we'd like to post, we can create an `NSMutableURLRequest`, and include our `postData`.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://YourURL.com/FakeURL"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

And finally, we can send our request, and read the reply by creating a new `NSURLSession`:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
}] resume];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce  i have to customize my api

Comment: i have an out put i.e video  recored video  url and every time i record video  the video name changes with time stamp. it is like instagram app

Comment: Request Data are not same every-time only parameter names are same

Comment: - (void)saveRecordedFile:(NSURL *)recordedFile {
 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
         ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedFile
                                         completionBlock:
         ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
 NSString *title;
                 NSString *message;
 NSLog(@"%@",recordedFile);
  
             });
         }];

Comment: recordedFile her i am getting out put and the out put is file:////var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5421D684-D466-44F1-AEF5-7390598B5647/Documents/2016-07-29-17-00-12-0.MOV i want to use this out put in the api

Comment: ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [assetLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:recordedFile
                                         completionBlock:
         ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
             
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^

Comment: out put is in url formate and output has the path and the name and i want add this to the below api 139.162.12.178/mediaone/sample/instagram.php?url=<image_path>&image_name=<image_id>